# how to verify whether the observed data follows an additive noise model

Tags: machine-learning, causality, structural-equation-modeling

Many causal discovery methods assume the data follows an additive noise model. My question is, given an observed dataset, is there a way to assess the assumption? How to tell if the observed dataset follows an additive noise model? Thank you very much.

Comment: One approach is adjusting the noise level to check for the validity of the model. See:  [Causal Identification with Additive Noise Models: Quantifying the Effect of Noise](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08087)

Comment: @msuzen Hi, thanks for your comments. The paper you shared verifies an algorithm against different levels of noise, where the data is generated given ground-truth additive noise SEMs. On the other hand, my question is how to tell if the observed data has additive noise when the ground-truth SEMs that generate the data are unknown. I don't know how to adjust the noise level if everything we have is the data (the data is a result of the underlying unknown SEM and noises).